# Install4j Get list of files in default file set

Tags: install4j

Is there a way to get the list of files contained in the default file set?

The closest thing I see in the API is getFileSets() but this returns only the additional file sets, so in my case it always returns an empty collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of install4j 5.1, there is no way to do so. The "Install files" action has a "File filter" property that is called for all installed files.